# Normal routes stop working after adding MapMvcAttributeRoutes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, custom-attributes

I have the following code in my `RouteConfig`:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Transfer",
            url: "Transfer/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional });

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Director",
            "{*parameters}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}
        );
    }
```

Everything works well, but whenever I uncomment the `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` line, only Attribute route works, the other cannot. Here is my controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [Route(""), Route("Home")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return this.View();
    }

    [Route("ContactUs")]
    public ActionResult ContactUs()
    {
        return this.View();
    }

    [Route("PrivacyPolicy")]
    public ActionResult PrivacyPolicy()
    {
        return this.View();
    }

    [Route("TermsOfUse")]
    public ActionResult TermsOfUse()
    {
        return this.View();
    }

}
```

What is the cause of this? It seem to first happens to me. I have done this many times previously but this problem never happened.

Comment: Seems that even I can't reproduce described behavior... try finding out with Phil's [RouteDebugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/) and edit your question with results for convention-based routes.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong here :

Try this way :

```
[Route("Home")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return this.View();
}
```